# Как вставить текст из одного файла в конец другого файла

Tags: linux, unix, sed

Как вставить текст из одного файла в конец другого файла, именно во вторую строку?

Есть такой ansible host file

```
[production]
linux1  ansible_host=

[same_cred:children]
production
```

Нужно  после `ansible_host=` вставить текст из другого файла, в котором находится IP адрес, только он в том файле.

Comment: То есть, во втором файле нет ничего, кроме одной строчки с *IP*-адресом?

Comment: Нет,только ip address, из него нужно в то месте вставить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это простой скрипт для *AWK*:

```awk
/ansible_host=$/ {
    getline ip < "./ip.txt";
    print($0 ip);
}
! /ansible_host=$/ {
    print($0);
}
```

Comment: Как то это не работает у меня, а не подскажите как это сделать через sed

Comment: «Не работает» не информативно.  Что и как не работает?  Убедитесь, что вы подставили имя файла с айпишником, а также, что в хост-файле после `ansible_host=` строка заканчивается, а не пробелы какие-нибудь.

Comment: И да, на *sed* тоже можно, но это будет сложнее, и я ещё не настолько мастер *sed*'а.

Comment: `sed -i -e "/ansible_host=/ s,$,$(cat ./ip.txt)\n," $MY_ANSIBLE_FILE_CONF` не сработает? Там дальше можно  крутить на тему... (я помню, что sed умел вроде из другого фала в буфер догружать, так что *useless use of cat* by me :-) )

Comment: @0andriy  Ну-у-у, через `cat` и я могу.  Слабо с использованием команды [`r`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_03) :-P ?